# Layout constraint not updating for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

The effect I'm tying to achieve is making it feel like the UITableViewCell "widens" when it is selected. I do this by adding a subview (let's call it visibleView) to the UITableViewCell's content view, and then I adjust mainView when the cell is selected.

However, visibleView's size doesn't change upon selection. Code below:

```
class feedTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var visibleCell: UIView!
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        self.visibleCell = UIView()
        self.visibleCell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.visibleCell)
        
        visibleCell.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        visibleCell.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        visibleCell.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        visibleCell.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        
        visibleCell.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        visibleCell.backgroundColor = .white
        
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        
        if selected {
            self.visibleCell.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
            self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
        } else {            
            self.visibleCell.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
            self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

However, if I replace layout constraints with frames and instead update visibleCell by adjusting its frame, everything works fine.

Comment: You have to remove the previous width constraint before you add a new one. They are not exchanged. Hold a reference to the constraint to be able to remove it before you add the new constraint.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that layout constraints didn't work like that. Please submit as the official answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the previous width constraint before you add a new one. They are not exchanged. Hold a reference to the constraint to be able to remove it before you add the new constraint.